# Converting string containing decimal code to plain string

Tags: javascript, string, encoding, utf-8

I am getting strings from an API endpoint like: `Senol Güne&#351; Spor Kompleksi`. `&#351;` is a Turkish letter, `ş`. I want my string to be `Senol Güneş  Spor Kompleksi`. I tried `JSON.Parse` and [utf8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8) package without success. Can I parse this string to a plain string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: @ASDFGerte a possible solution to that, decode-html package did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using [html-entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities) package.

```
const Entities = require('html-entities').AllHtmlEntities;
const entities = new Entities();
const decodedString = entities.decode(originalString);
```